# How to solve java.security.NoSuchProviderException

Tags: java, security, cryptography, nosuchproviderexception

I have successfully installed cryptography library on my machine, so that after installation I see these lines in `jre\lib\security\java.security`:

```
security.provider.11=ru.CryptoPro.JCP.JCP
security.provider.12=ru.CryptoPro.Crypto.CryptoProvider
security.provider.13=ru.CryptoPro.reprov.RevCheck
security.provider.14=ru.CryptoPro.ssl.Provider
security.provider.15=ru.CryptoPro.JCSP.JCSP
```

These lines appeared in `java.security` file automatically. Besides, when I import needed modules, I do not get any error:

```
import ru.CryptoPro.JCP.*;
import ru.CryptoPro.JCP.KeyStore.*;
import ru.CryptoPro.JCP.params.JCPProtectionParameter;
import ru.CryptoPro.JCSP.JCSP;
```

It is totally ok. When, however, I add one tiny command to my code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("REGISTRY", JCSP.PROVIDER_NAME);
```

I get a long list of errors:

```
java.security.NoSuchProviderException: no such provider: JCSP at  
sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getService(Unknown Source) at 
sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.Security.getImpl(Unknown Source) at 
java.security.KeyStore.getInstance(Unknown Source) at 
com.test.examples.Test.doGet(Test.java:40) at 
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) at
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) at 
... list goes on
```

What are possible reasons of these error messages?

Comment: Perhaps there is a different JDK/JRE at work when run it compared to your IDE.

Comment: Seems, like you are right. I've just executed unit tests of this library and they are ok. Now I will check my IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the similar issue with different security provider (`ERACOM`) and solved it with explicit provider registration:

```
Security.addProvider(new ERACOMProvider());
```

Try to register your provider in the same way, just create and instance and register it with `java.security.Security#addProvider` method. I hope, it will help you.